# How to programmatically access this Active Directory as LocalService?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, windows-services

Trying to access the local ActiveDirectory from my Windows Service.

I was going to try using the `LocalService` to access it, it works when I run it inside Visual Studio as Administrator, but failed when I run it as an actual Service.

Do I need to provide the `SecurityIdentifier` to `DirectoryEntry` somehow? But it only takes `username` and `password` and not `SecurityIdentifier`...

```
var fqhn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName;
using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/RootDSE", fqhn)))
{ 
    string ctx = root.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
    string path = string.Format("LDAP://{0}/CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,{1}", 
                                fqhn, ctx);
    var blah = new DirectoryEntry(path);
}
```

It gives me 
`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072030): There is no such object on the server.`, I've tried running the service in both `LocalService` or `NetworkService`.

Comment: Neither `LocalService` nor `NetworkService` will have permissions to connect to your active directory as they are local computer accounts. You can try `System`, which will use the computer account in AD, but really you should run your service as an AD user so you can assign only the permissions needed.

Comment: Hum... new with C# here, so there is no way to use the system accounts to read the AD?? I really want to avoid creating new users. In the `Active Directory Users and Computers > Users`, if I add `NETWORK SERVICE` or `LOCAL SERVICE` via the `Delegation Control Wizard`, would that work?

Comment: No, since each computer including your computer and the AD servers have their own network and local service accounts. Why wouldn't you want to create a user? Either way, the only account on your computer that could access stuff in AD is the System (computer) account.

Comment: @Ashigore, NetworkService should work, it will use the computer's AD account the same way as System would.  (That's the difference between NetworkService and LocalService.)

Comment: Does the code work when run as a non-administrative user?

Comment: Interesting, on my development machine, it runs even with non-administrative user, but then I just setup my own AD there, so not sure if i set it up correctly. On the integration server, it runs a proper AD, perhaps I need to manually add NetworkService to have permission on the AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like I was using the wrong address to access the ActiveDirectory. On my local machine, I was using:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName;
```

But I should be using the **domain** instead:

```
Environment.UserDomainName
```

So I kind of made a fallback approach in case the domain is not there...

```
string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
    domain = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName;
```

Now connecting to the LDAP works:

```
new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/RootDSE", domain)
```

And just to confirm what @Harry Johnston said in the other reply, using `NetworkService` worked! (I reverted back to `LocalService` just to be sure and it failed on me)